# Confusion with BEM class naming convention. One level deeper

Tags: html, css, class, naming-conventions, bem

For example I have a menu block with menu elements:

```
.menu
.menu__element
.menu__element--current
```

But lets say `.menu` block is contained inside another block, `.header`

How to deal with naming in this case?

```
.header 
.header__menu 
.header__element
```

or

```
.header 
.header__menu 
.header__menu__element
```

or

```
.header 
.menu 
.menu__element
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu should be a class unto itself so .menu should suffice. If it's a menu that is ONLY in a header and never anywhere else, then .header-menu. Then you can point to the menu directly without going through the header class.

If you prefer to do it the way you outlined, then .header_menu.

Answer (score 8):

Consider using "mixes" (more than one BEM entity on the same DOM-node):

```
<div class="header">
    <ul class="menu header__menu">
        <li class="menu__element"></li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

So block **menu** is also element **header__menu** at the same time. That gives you the ability to apply styles for any abstract menu and add special rules for that particular menu inside the header.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="header">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu__element">...</li>
        <li class="menu__element menu__element--current">...</li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>    

.header {...}
.menu {...}
.menu__element {...}
.menu__element--current {...}
```

will be right.

Block name does not change when block inserted into another block.

BEM prohibits put an elements in the elements and write classnames like `block__element__element`, more info: [How to properly set an element's scope using BEM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894664/how-to-properly-set-an-elements-scope-using-bem/27900589#answer-27900589)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the official documentation of BEM says (http://getbem.com/faq/#css-nested-elements);

[image]

No matter how deep you're nesting, you always use the top parent as block element. So basically it would be;

```
.header 
.header__menu 
.header__element
```