# How to properly set an element's scope using BEM?

Tags: css, naming-conventions, bem

Given the following BEM tree structure, where five nested levels exist:

```
collection-main__features-top__story__byline__author
```

according to BEM's naming convention, where an element is part of a block and has no meaning outside of the block it belongs to, what is the proper way to name the `author` class?

Since an `author` is semantically tied to the `byline` and the `story` context, but meaningless under the `features-top` and `collection-main` blocks, what is the best BEM name?

```
collection-main__author
features-top__author
story__author (best?)
story__byline__author
byline__author
```

What happens if a new `features` block gets introduced?

```
collection-main__features-top__story__byline__author (target)
collection-main__features-bottom__story__byline__author

features-top__story__author
story--features-top__author (best?)
```

Finally, what happens if another `collection` block gets added and we want to style the second author element in the list?

```
collection-main__features-top__story__byline__author
collection-main__features-bottom__story__byline__author (target)
collection-sub__features-top__story__byline__author
collection-sub__features-bottom__story__byline__author
```

Would we do something like this?

```
story--collection-main--features-bottom__author
```

There must be a better option.

Comment: Please, show your data to output. Is it like 

`{collection-main: [{"feature-item": { story: {author: ''} } }]}` ?

Answer (score 41):

**BEM prohibits put an elements in the elements in CSS!**
You make the most typical error in BEM markup - writing a `block__element__element`.
You must create new blocks, rather than copying DOM-tree.

For example:
Right HTML:

```
<div class='block'>
    <div class='block__elem1'>
        <div class='block__elem2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='block__elem3'></div>
</div>
```

Right CSS:

```
.block {}
.block__elem1 {}
.block__elem2 {}
.block__elem3 {}
```

**If you need to make an element of an element, then you need to make a new block or make your bem-tree with a single nested elements!**

WRONG:

```
<div class='block'>
    <div class='block__elem1'>
        <div class='block__elem1__elem2'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

RIGHT #1: Make a new block

```
<div class='block1'>
    <div class='block2'>
        <div class='block2__elem'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

RIGHT #2: Make your bem-tree with a single nested elements

```
<div class='block'>
    <div class='block__elem1'>
        <div class='block__elem2'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Pay attention - you can not put elements in a elements in the css, but you can and should put elements in a elements into html! DOM-tree and BEM-tree can be different.*

**Do not write strange names, putting the element name in the name of the block!**

WRONG:

```
.block {}
.block-elem1 {}
.block-elem1__elem2 {}
```

Because you get a problem with odd names when you try to move the block:

```
<div class='other-block'>
    <div class='block-elem1'></div>
</div>
```

Nested html-elements is a DOM-tree.
The names of the classes you write is a BEM-tree.
Feel the difference!

DOM-tree:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

.ul {}
.ul > li {}
.ul > li > a {}
.ul > li > a > span {}
```

BEM-tree:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link">
      <span class="menu__text"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

.menu {}
.menu__item {}
.menu__link {}
.menu__text {}
```

References:

> "An element is a constituent part of a block that can't be used outside of it."
>   https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#element

An element is a part of a block! Not part of element!
Read Vitaly Harisov, the author of BEM-methodology: https://twitter.com/harisov/status/403421669974618112

> Classname like "block__elem__elem___elem" means that coder didn't understand anything in BEM.

Read also:

- https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#why-does-bem-not-recommend-using-elements-within-elements-block__elem1__elem2
- http://getbem.com/faq/#css-nested-elements

There is a report (in Russian) on a web conference WebCamp: Front-end Developers Day about this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBgHdSOj33A
+ slides: http://ihorzenich.github.io/talks/2015/frontendweekend-bem/